# Remove part of route from Google DirectionsRenderer

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, directions

Is there a way to remove only a part from the directions result from Google? Reason I'm asking is because there's a limit of 2.500 direction requests/day but in my app I'd like to update the displayed route to the point where a user is at a given time.

So say I have a route from A to B which covers 500m and I started moving from A towards B in any direction, I'd like to clear the route to the point where the user has the closest match to pick up the route again.

Is this possible or do I need to recalculate the directions each time watchPosition() fires?

Answer (score 0):

You can break them down into different routes but still drawing it together as a same route. You can do this by cutting the waypoints into different routes calling the directions renderer each time as if you are using a different route. The key is after the first route that the next route has to start with the last waypoint of the previous route (this makes sure that the route lines are connected to each other).